# Distributed Job Execution framework

Tags: java

**My Requirement:**

- Need to monitor large number of Web Application instances
- Need to gather transaction time for each clicks, push that time into
  central Database.

**My Progress:**

Already identified libraries like htmlunit to develop tool to handle Web Applications Authentication, browse/scrape Web Apps

**Looking for framework:**

- Framework which can execute monitoring jobs on mutliple systems (distributed executions)
- Possibly based on Java but it's ok if i can get anything based on Python, Perl or other langs

Any architecture details of Apps/Solutions like site24x7 would be of great help :)

thank you,

Comment: Well, Jenkins/Hudson, which are actually distributed CI systems, could work for your use...

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: this answer is about requirements listed in your post body.*

Look at [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). It collects a huge set of different statistics data. It also can do some centralized statistics collection from a distributed application.

Answer (score 0):

something these guys are doing - http://arvan.in/monitoring-web-applications/

The Arvan does monitoring on web application where JavaScript disabled command line browser tools can not browse the web applications.

thx